# Disable hyperlinks but keep functionality of this javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio, playlist

I'm creating an audioplayer with a playlist and I use javascript to recognize links as songs and put them in a playlist.

```
<a href="media/example/01.wav"></a>
<a href="media/example/01.wav"></a>
<a href="media/example/01.wav"></a>
```

This is the script I use

```
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;
init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('.player');
    playlist = $('.album_tracks_container');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length;
    var currentPlaylist;
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        currentPlaylist = link.closest('.album_tracks_container'); // <---
        run(link, audio[0]);
        $('.audioplayer').removeClass('audioplayer-stopped');
        $('.audioplayer').addClass('audioplayer-playing');
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = currentPlaylist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = currentPlaylist.find('a')[current];   
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
        $('.audioplayer').removeClass('audioplayer-stopped');
        $('.audioplayer').addClass('audioplayer-playing');
    });
}
function run(link, player){
    $('.album_tracks_container').find('.album_tracks_light, .album_tracks_dark').removeClass('album_tracks_active');
    player.src = link.attr('href');
    par = link.parent();
    par.addClass('album_tracks_active').siblings().removeClass('album_tracks_active');
    $('.album_tracks_container').find('.album_tracks_light, .album_tracks_dark').find('.album_tracks_number, .album_tracks_text').removeClass('album_tracks_number-text_active');
    par.find('.album_tracks_number, .album_tracks_text').addClass('album_tracks_number-text_active');
    audio[0].load();
    audio[0].play();
}
```

Now, my problem is that my audioplayer is at the bottom of the page, and as you hover the links, the chrome hyperlink popup will partially cover it. Is it possible to disable the hyperlinks but keep the functionality of selecting tracks through links href?

Alternatively, is it possible to turn the links into a span or something and have the javascript recognize the text in it instead?

Or as a last option, can I simply hide Chromes (and others browsers) hyperlink popup display?

Comment: you can use span in combination of html5 data attributes, something like <span data-href="media/example1.wav"></span> and later on : $('span').data('href') since jQuery data reads html5 data attributes as well .. you can also read that with .attr('data-href') etc.

Comment: I used this

<span class="span-link" data="media/example/01.wav"></span>

and changed these lines in the script

playlist.find('a').click(function(e){

player.src = link.attr('href');

to this

playlist.find('.span-link').click(function(e){

player.src = link.attr('data');

Thank you Goran.it and mplungjan for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to remove the href attribute, try to use "data-file" instead. Also You'll need to  change the folowing line

```
player.src = link.attr('href');
```

to

```
player.src = link.data().file;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn `<span>` element into a clickable element (with behavior similar to a link).

Here an example:

```
$('span.link').click(function(e){
    alert('Hello!');
   // put the action of your <a> here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bruno2c/c2KYm/4/